# Rails: How to call ApplicationController method WITH ARGS from a controller's before_action/after_action method INLINE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my `set_pagination_header` on Application Controller and I need to call it from some other controller:

```
# syntax error in line below
after_action :set_pagination_header, :my_argument_object, only: [:index]

def index
  @my_argument_object = Resource.page(1)
  render json: @my_argument_object
end
```

Can I directly send the original `@my_argument_object` so I don't want to do:

```
def set_pagination_header(name, options = {})
    scope = instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
    # some_logic_here
end
```

1) What is the right syntax (need an inline one) ?

2) **Why not `set_pagination_header(object, options = {})` be the definition?**

---

**EDIT**: I found something [here](https://jaketrent.com/post/pagination-headers-with-kaminari/#pagination-headers) like

```
after_filter only: [:index] { set_pagination_header(:germs) }
```

It's old syntax, we got after_action now. Nonetheless I believe there's an **inline** way to do that, isn't it?

```
# I tried and that didn't work
after_action :set_pagination_header(:my_argument_object), only: [:index]
after_action { :set_pagination_header(:my_argument_object) } only: [:index]
after_action { :set_pagination_header, :my_argument_object } only: [:index]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline way, but not so clean!

```
after_action Proc.new{ set_pagination_header(:paged_orders) }, only: [:index]
```

Comment: and still not figured out if it's possible to send the hash as args instead of mere string name which would want me to pick the right reference using that string

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to add a method call to your callback

```
after_action :set_pagination_header_callback, only: :index

def set_pagination_header_callback
  set_pagination_header(...your variables here...)
end

# application_controller.rb
def set_pagination_header(name, options = {})
  scope = instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
  # some_logic_here
end
```

Comment: :( sorry, I was expecting an inline way to do it, just made an edit to the question: forgot to mention it, my bad!